# Segmentation fault in vim and vifm

Tags: vim, xterm, segmentation-fault, vifm

What does this error mean?

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
```

I get it randomly when I close `vifm` or `vim` in an `xterm` terminal.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you try it in a different terminal emulator to see if you get the same behavior?

Comment: Yes a different terminal emulator stops the problem but I am wondering why I am having it in the first place. Other terminal emulators don't seem to feel as responsive as xterm.